# Android Vertex Array Objects?

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertex-array-object, vao

I am writing some android code in preparation for a graphics intensive app I plan to develop. I haven't done any OpenGL since 2004. I stumbled across http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Array_Object and multiple sources for the PC platform claim that using vertex-array-objects is the best way to render.

My target platform is a Motorola Atrix 2 smart-phone with Android 2.3.

I can't seem to find an include for a function corresponding to GL_OES_vertex_array_object. I want to call functions similar to glGenVertexArraysOES.

How do I use VAOs in Android?

My current includes are

```
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VAOs` are fairly new and not included in OpenGL|ES 1.0 or 1.1 (not to be confused with `Buffer Objects`, or as they're sometimes called `VBOs`). You'll have to import and use OpenGL|ES 2.0, and by doing that you'll have to make some changes to your graphics code to draw via shaders instead of `glVertexPointer` and similar methods. From the looks of it, there's no `GL20Ext` class or similar built into Android, I would look around the web for bindings or write them myself using the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

On some devices the VAO extension is not implemented. First check the OpenGl ES version with

```
gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION);
```

Then check if the extension is availbale with

```
gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

it should contain: GL_OES_vertex_array_object

For more info about extensions: [OpenGL extensions available on different Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594/opengl-extensions-available-on-different-android-devices)

For more info about VAOs on android check: [OES_vertex_array_object and client state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536973/oes-vertex-array-object-and-client-state)

Edit: Change answer to respond the question right. Thx for the comment.

Comment: He is asking about VAO, not VBO.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry. At-least the extension stuff still applies here.